# Use scanf(), gets() or fgets() function?

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets, spaces

I am trying to encrypt a string by Caesar encryption, but it only works for one word (no spaces between characters). I would like to encrypt whole sentence. I have read here about getting white spaces from keyboard into a string by `gets()` or `fgets()`, but I cannot make it functional.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Enter the shift: ");
    int shift,index,length;
    scanf("%d", &shift);

    printf("Enter the string to encrypt: " );
    char string[1000];
    //gets(string);
    scanf("%s",string);
    //fgets(string,1000,stdin);

    char encrypted[strlen(string) + 1];

    for(index = 0, length = strlen(string); index < length; index++ ){
        if (string[index]!=' ')
            encrypted[index] = 'A' + (string[index] -'A' + shift) % 26;
        else
            encrypted[index]=' ';
    }
    encrypted[ strlen(string)] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", encrypted);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: How are your attempts "not functional"?  What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: Replace the `scanf` with either a loop or a call to `fgets` -- lookup documentation using `man fgets`

Comment: Please forget you ever heard about `gets`: It's just about impossible to use that safely.

Comment: Never ever use `gets()`, even in practice programs. [It is a horrible security hole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036).

Comment: for example: for input `string` "MY NAME" with shift 1 I expect variable `encrypted` to be"NZ OBNF", but for this code it would be only "NZ"

Comment: try `scanf(" %999[^\n]", string);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY THANKS! this one works.

Comment: `scanf(" %999[^\n]", string);`, though not bad, does not retain leading spaces.

Comment: @chux It is a good indication.

Comment: It is true, it ignores leading spaces, but they are not needed so far.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
char string[1000];
scanf("%s",string);
```

the scan terminates at whitespace.

To get the whole string (excluding the trailing newline) use:

```
char string[1000], *p;
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
if ((p = strchr(string, '\n')) != NULL) { 
    *p = '\0'; /* remove newline */
}
```

As pointed out by @chux you need to consume `\n` in `scanf`, I suggest:

```
int shift, index, length;
char string[1000], *p;

fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
shift = atoi(string);
printf("Enter the string to encrypt: " );
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
if ((p = strchr(string, '\n')) != NULL) { 
    *p = '\0'; /* remove newline */
}
```

And you get:

```
Enter the shift: 1
Enter the string to encrypt: MY NAME
NZ OBNF
```

Comment: Likely has same problem as @Tom. `scanf("%d", &shift);` leaves a `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `scanf("%s",string);`. That stops as soon as it hits
whitespace. Instead, use

```
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
```

(Note that it's not a great idea to allocate a large string with
something like `char string[1000];` -- in most implementations, it goes
on the stack. `malloc` is better.)

Comment: I have already tried this, but program does NOT wait for my input. It allways put only '@' character as input string and then nothing happens.

Comment: @Dounchan change `scanf("%d", &shift);` to `fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); sscanf(string, "%d", &shift);`

Answer (score 0):

The remaining line breaks without being consumed in the part of `scanf("%d", &shift)`.
So, it appears that fgets and gets you to enter a new line up to not function.(Because they are given a new line remaining)

```
while(getchar()!='\n');//get rid of the newline up
scanf("%999[^\n]", string);//It corresponds to the `gets()`
```